# laravel 5 - creating a new "thing" in a controller method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm looking at this tutorial here:
http://laravel.com/docs/master/quickstart-intermediate#creating-the-task.

But rather than follow it blindly, I'm trying to make it relevant to my needs. I have come across a problem. I'm looking at this code:

```
/**
 * Create a new task.
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    $request->user()->tasks()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);

    return redirect('/tasks');
}
```

Ok. So in my application I want to create a country. No user associated with it, it's just a form posting the name of a country to this route. My form passes validation and if I use the following code, I can save the new country record to my database:

If I substitute

```
$request->user()->tasks()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
    ]);
```

with...

```
$country = new Country;
$country ->name = $request->name;
$country ->save();
```

...then this works out ok. I don't really want this though.

What I would like to do is use something similar to the code in the tutorial.
Can anyone tell me what I should do please?

I have tried a few different guesses, but no luck. They are exactly that tho. Guesses...

Thanks.

DS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you see in the tutorial can be summarized as "create a task for given user". Creating **Task** objects the way you can see in the tutorial is possible because there is a relation set between **User** and **Task** model - see **tasks()** method in **User** class. That's why you can, given **$user** stores an object of class **User**, call **$user->tasks()->create()** - as a result an object of class **Task** will be created and automatically linked to that user.

If you want to create objects of class **Country** the same way, there needs to be a relation defined between countries and users - but while it makes sense in case of tasks (users have their own tasks), it doesn't sound like something you want in your application (users have their own countries?).

Comment: Hi @jedrzej - thanks for the comment. yes, after some looking around, I realised there doesn't really seem to be a better way to do it than: $country = Country::create($request->only('name'));     which is fine for my needs. thanks for taking the time to post your thoughts.